# Reversing a number that has a zero at the last place

Tags: c

```
reverse = reverse * 10;
reverse = reverse + (n % 10);
n = n / 10;
```

This prints `51` instead of `051`.

What needs to change in the logic in order to get the output as `051`?

Comment: Hint: Consider implementing the same using `char` array.

Comment: If(number%10==0) reverse(number)

Comment: There is no way to reverse an `int` that way. You need to reverse a string of characters.

Comment: You cannot store leading zeros in any numeric type, so you cannot print zeros that aren't there.

Comment: The logic is correct but leading zeroes mean nothing in integer types. Change your objective (add "leading zeroes are not significant"), or change your code to store the result in a character array.

Comment: @barak manos:  *"There is no way to reverse an int that way."* I showed a way to reverse an int using this technique, with a very small adjustment.  See my answer below

Comment: @abelenky: Of course you could "trick your way around it", but you ended up printing zeros which were not "a part" of the `int`. What I meant to say is, that using an `int` alone (without any "string help") could not yield the desired output. Of course you could claim that any call to `printf` eventually makes use of a string in one way or another. But my point was to tell OP that his idea of differentiating between `int n = 51` and `int n = 051` was not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the `whole reverse number` in `one place` just use an array like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n=15000;
    char reverse[11]; // change the array size depending on integer value type
    int ind=0;
    while(n)
    {
        int digit = n%10;
        reverse[ind++] = digit + '0';
        n = n / 10;
    }
    reverse[ind]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",reverse);

    // If you want the decimal value you can simply do this
    int decimal_val=atoi(reverse);
    printf("%d\n",decimal_val);
    return 0;
}
```

There can be another way if you want to use string function :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 3505000;
    char rev[15];
    itoa(n,rev,10);
    strrev(rev);
    puts(rev);
}
```

Here `itoa(number, target_string, number_base)` // Here `n` is a decimal number, so `base=10`
and `strrev()` reverses the string.

Comment: Actually my previous example holds the same number...
Thats why i used it

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int number = 150, temp = number, digit;

    while(temp != 0) {
        digit = temp%10;
        temp = temp /10;
        printf("%d", digit);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well,i don't think you understand what op says.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 while(num)
 {
  printf("%d\n",num%10);
  num/=10;
 }
```

to reverse an `int` variable named `num` . Or you can use the following(suggested by [@chux](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/27580854/reversing-a-number-that-has-a-zero-at-the-last-place/27580893#comment43589353_27580893)) which will print at least a 0 when `num` is 0:

```
 do
 {
  printf("%d\n",num%10);
  num/=10;
 }while(num);
```

This will also print zeros.But I think that you need the the reverse of a number stored in a variable.In short,you can't do this because 051 is not a decimal number.It is an octal number.Just print `0` when digit(s) in the units place are 0.The following program does this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> //for using boolean values

int main(void){
 int n=150,reverse=0;
 bool ranonce=false; 
 while(n)
 {
  if(ranonce==false && n%10==0) //if 0 is found when the boolean vaue if false
   putchar('0');                //print a '0'
  reverse = reverse * 10;
  reverse = reverse + (n % 10);
  n = n / 10;

  if(n%10!=0) //if more zeros are not found in `n`
   ranonce=true;
 }
 printf("%d\n",reverse);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest `do { printf("%d\n",num%10); num/=10; } while (num)` so when `num==0`, something is printed.

Comment: Note that "051 is not a decimal number. It is an octal number" is *not the issue*; an easy counterexample is `80`. The issue at hand appears to be that OP expects leading zeroes to be preserved in *any* numeric variable.

Answer (score 0):

This reverse function keeps track of the size of the number, via out-param, `psz`.

So for your test input of 510, the return value is `15`, with `*psz = 3`, making it easy to print `015`.

```
int reverse(int input, int* psz)
{
    int output = 0;

    *psz = 0;
    while(input)
    {
        output *= 10;
        output += (input % 10);
        input /= 10;
        (*psz)++;
    }

    return output;
}

int main()
{
    int input = 510;
    int sz;

    int out=reverse(input, &sz);

    printf("%0*d\n", sz, out);   // Output: 015

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be another way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n=15000;
    char reverse[15];
    itoa(n,reverse,10); // Here 10 is the base. Means decimal number
    strrev(reverse);
    printf("%s\n",reverse);
    return 0;
}
```